# Nemitski loss function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, definition

I have the following Problem:
A loss $L: X \times Y \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ is called a Nemitski loss if there exist a measurable function $b: X \times Y \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ and an increasing function $h:[0, \infty) \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ such that
$$
L(x, y, t) \leq b(x, y)+h(|t|), \quad(x, y, t) \in X \times Y \times \mathbb{R} .
$$
And $L$ is called marginbased if there exists a representing function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ such that
$$
L(x, y, t)=\varphi(y t), \quad y \in Y, t \in \mathbb{R} .
$$

Now according to the lemma i found it holds:
For $Y=\{1,-1\}$, $L$ is a Nemitski loss if L is marginbased. And the whole proof was:
$$L(y, t) \leq \max \{\varphi(-t), \varphi(t)\}, \quad y \in Y, t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
So i guess the function on the right hand side represents $h(|t|)$ from the definition? but why is this function increasing?

Comment: Is it possible that you miss a continuity condition for the representing function in the marginbased definition? In general this seems not to be true. For example (for $Y=\{\pm 1\}$) $$L(x,y,t)=\begin{cases} ( 1-\vert t \vert )^{-2},& t\neq 1,\\ 0,& t=1.\end{cases}$$ is marginbased, but not a Loss function according to your definition.

Comment: If you additionally ask for $\varphi$ to be continuous in your definition of marginbased, it works. You can just pick $$h(\vert t\vert)=\max_{s\in [-\vert t\vert, \vert t\vert]} \varphi(s).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But no, in the book isn`t anything mentioned about the continouity of $\phi$. But maybe i should have mentioned that L must be measurable per Defintion. But i dont see how this should help.

Comment: It does not rule out my counterexample. I guess they just forgot the continuity condition.